# C: Clearing stdin input buffer not working as expected with fgets()

Tags: c, macos, stdin, eof, fgets

I am using the following method clear the input buffer:

```
void dump_line(FILE *fp) {
    int ch;    
    while ( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}
```

This works fine if I read from stdin using scanf():

```
char string[51];
...
scanf("%50[^\n]", string);
dump_line(stdin);
```

However, if I use fgets() instead, as in the following code:

```
char string[52];
...
fgets(string, 52, stdin);
dump_line(stdin);

// Since fgets() reads in the '\n', trim the end of the string:
string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;
```

Since fgets() reads in the '\n' character I found the need to allocate a buffer one char larger and trim the string back one character. This works fine but there is a problem with the dump_line function. When using the scanf() version, it works as expected since there will always be a '\n' left in the input buffer due to the use of [^\n]. So even if that is the only char left in the buffer, in dump_line() the fgetc() reads the char and since it is a '\n' the while loop is broken.

In the fgets() version, the '\n' is read in if it will fit in the string buffer, leaving stdin empty. This is causing the program to wait on the fgetc(), requiring the user to hit the enter key to progress any further, which is obviously not what I am after. On the other hand, if the user enters a string too long for the buffer, the dump_line() is working fine!

Im guessing the problem is something to do with EOF, but I cannot seem to get this to work as intended! Any help would greatly be appreciated.

If it is any help the platform I am working on is Mac OSX, just in case this is some kind of platform-specific quirk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether you need to clear the buffer,

```
fgets(string, 52, stdin);
size_t len = strlen(string);
if (string[len-1] == '\n') {
    // read in whole line, no need to clear buffer
    string[len-1] = 0;
} else {
    // junk left in buffer, clear it
    dump_line(stdin);
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to do, but should the line 'while ( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && ch != '\n');' not simply break if it encounters the end of the file, rather then waiting on the fgetc(), otherwise the '!= EOF' seems completely redundant. Or does this EOF only work for file input, and stdin is a special case that should considered to not have an end of file, hence the wait for input? If i'm making any sense here!

Comment: You get `EOF` when the end of the stream is reached. For `stdin`, you can make that happen with Ctrl+D (Ctrl+Z on Windows, iirc). When the input stream has not reached the end and there just is currently no more data available, `fgetc` blocks until either data becomes available or the end of the stream is detected. Since the stream may be corrupted without encountering a newline, the `EOF` check is not redundant (although in practice, it's rarely triggered on `stdin`).

Comment: Thanks for that information, I understand what was going on better now. So the best thing to do as you originally suggested would be to check if the last char is '\n', if so trim the string, if not we know there is junk in left in stdin so run the dump_line(). I guess I was simply under the illusion that the given dump_line function would do nothing if the stdin buffer was empty! Thanks for your help! Im guessing for an input other than stdin fgetc() would not block and hit the EOF and stop as expected then?

Comment: Well, it blocks until it either gets data or the end of the stream is detected in any case. Just with files on the local disk, that happens so fast that you don't notice.

Comment: Got it. I guess that because I was under the impression that it wasn't blocking when reading for a file, I was wondering why it was blocking when used with stdin! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ungetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc) to put the newline back into the stream.

Comment: Ahh, so just simply put a newline character back in using this at the top of the dump_line function to deal with this problem.. but as per my comment on the above reply, should the EOF simply be detected by the loop and break it, or does EOF not work with stdin?

Comment: @tom1990 You get EOF from `stdin` only when the user actually does a EOF, i.e. presses CTRL-D on UNIX systems (like Linux and OSX) or CTRL-Z (on Windows).

Comment: Right, I understand. Thanks for your input, that explains why the while loop was not doing what I was expecting it to do! I was just going to replace the fgetc() with a scanf() and forget about it originally but I wanted to further understand why it was not doing what I though it would, because I didn't like having a gap in my C knowledge!